# route openvpn server traffic through wireguard client

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, wireguard

I have currently set up two vpn servers. one is a wireguard server and one is an openvpn server. I can successfully connect to internet through both VPN servers independently. But what I want to do is for the openvpn server to also act as the wireguard client so that when I connect to the openvpn server I actually have wireguard server's ip address on the internet. in short I want a double hop vpn so that I could access to the internet like this: my computer -> openvpn server -> wireguard server -> internet. so far I successfully set up the openvpn server to act as wireguard client. but when I connect to it through openvpn I can no longer access to the internet. I think there is some routing or firewall thing that I'm missing. I would really appreciate any help. These are routing tables, rules and iptables info:

```
default via 176.65.242.65 dev eth0 onlink 
10.8.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.8 
10.8.1.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.1 
176.65.242.64/26 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 176.65.242.124
```

```
0:  from all lookup local
32762:  from all sport 1194 lookup main
32763:  from all sport 22 lookup main
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  ip-10-8-1-0.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal/24  anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

p.s. my openvpn is running on port 1194 that's why I added the 1194 sport rule. And also I'm using 10.8.1 for my openvpn server and 10.8.0 for my wireguard server which is an aws ec2